# Let $f(x,y) = \frac {-1}4 (3xy^2 - 5x^3y + 2x^4)$. Find the equation of the tangent plane to $f$ at the point $(2,4)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $f(x,y) = \frac {-1}4 (3xy^2 - 5x^3y + 2x^4)$. Find the equation of the tangent plane to $f$ at the point $(2,4)$.

Using vector dot product with:

$a = 2$
$b = 4$
$f(a,b) = -8$
$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}(a,b) = -56$
$\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}(a,b) = -22$

I worked out the answer:

$56x + 22y - 2 = 192$

but according to the solution sheet this is wrong. Would really appreciate help on where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind showing us your partial derivatives? Because I got different figures than your -56 and -22

Comment: I opened up the brackets before I worked out the partial derivatives.

I got df/dx = (-3/4)y^2 - (15/4)x^2y + 2x^3

and df/dy = (-3/2)xy - (5/4)x^3

Sorry, I don't quite know how to write formulas yet.

Comment: Tutorial for formatting [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok, that -15/4 is wrong, it should be +15/4 in front of that x^2y

Comment: Wow, I feel like such an idiot. I've been sitting here stuck for hours. I didn't even think to check that because I just assumed I got that right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@samuel With the information above and the equation of a tangent plane to be $z-z_o=F_x(x-x_o)+F_y(y-y_o)$ you can now plug in all the info we have:
$z + 8 = 32 (x-2)-2(y-4)$ Work this out and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have

$$f(x,y) = -\frac{1}{4}(3xy^2 - 5x^3y + 2x^4).$$

Then, $$f_x(x,y) = -\frac{1}{4}(3y^2 - 15x^2y + 8x^3),$$

and

$$f_y(x,y) = -\frac{1}{4}(6xy - 5x^3).$$

From this I get $f_x(2,4) = 212$ and $f_y(2,4) = -2$, which doesn't agree with what you got.  Maybe that's why things aren't working out?

Comment: Would you mind explaining where this 212 comes from? I din't get that

Comment: $f_x(2,4)$ should be $32$.

Comment: Sorry, arithmetic error. Should be $32$: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-1/4)(3 \cdot 4^2 - 15 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 4 + 8 \cdot 2^3) = 32.$$

Comment: @Bye_World Yep, thanks.